# Python readline and UTF-8

Tags: python, macos, unicode, readline

I'm trying to use raw_input() with readline and utf-8 encoding (on OSX 10.6.8).

Imagine the following snippet:

```
import readline

while True: 
    try:
        inp = raw_input('> ')
    except EOFError:
        break
```

This works except when trying to type non standard ASCII letters, say 'å' or 'ä'. When doing this no input is written, I guess readline is filtering this somehow.

I then changed the input encoding using

```
sys.stdin = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdin)
```

Now typing 'å' and 'ä' works but it seems the readline functionality is no more.

Any ideas on how to make readline cope with unicode letters?

Comment: I know OSX ships with an inferior equivalent to readline (for licensing reasons). If you do `easy_install readline` and then try, does it change anything? FWIW, the same thing works for me on Linux.

Comment: Not trying to change the input encoding and following @ThomasK tip solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @lode: Your program works, on my Mac OS X (10.7: Lion), with the standard Python installation.  (My terminal works in UTF-8.)  What version of Mac OS X are you using?

Comment: @EOL: I'm running 10.6.8 (snow leopard), Python 2.6.1. Terminal is using UTF-8. Seems like this was only due to an old version of the readline module. Glad they fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Reposting as an answer): OSX ships with an inferior equivalent to readline called libedit (for licensing reasons, it can't ship readline itself).

You can do `easy_install readline` to get GNU readline in Python on a Mac.

This also causes a problem for IPython, which now displays an ugly warning if it detects that libedit is in use.

Comment: Note that editline (libedit) is simply a BSD variant of readline that already appeared in 4.4BSD…